# Can you identify these cryptographic algorithmic symbols?

Tags: hash, notation, ripemd

I am mostly self taught and have limited knowledge of the symbology in the image below. It is a diagram of a sub block the RIPEMD-160 algorithm:

[image: A sub-block from the compression function of the RIPEMD-160 hash algorithm]

Are such symbols standardized? Is there a good dictionary or atlas someone is aware of that could link such symbols to their definitions?

Here is the source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is RIPEMD-160 and [the paper describes them as](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ebosselae/ripemd160/pdf/AB-9601/AB-9601.pdf);

- $f$ represents nonlinear functions at bit level: $exor, mux, -, mux, -$ and varies with rounds;

  - $f(j, x, y, z) = x ⊕ y ⊕ z \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (0 ≤ j ≤ 15)$
  - $f(j, x, y, z) = (x ∧ y) ∨ (¬x ∧ z) \quad (16 ≤ j ≤ 31)$
  - $f(j, x, y, z) = (x ∨ ¬y) ⊕ z \quad \quad \quad (32 ≤ j ≤ 47)$
  - $f(j, x, y, z) = (x ∧ z) ∨ (y ∧ ¬z) \quad (48 ≤ j ≤ 63)$
  - $f(j, x, y, z) = x ⊕ (y ∨ ¬z) \quad \quad \quad (64 ≤ j ≤ 79)$
- $\boxplus$ denotes addition modulo $2^{32}$
- $rol_s$ denotes cyclic left shift (rotate) over $s$ positions.
  in the figure there is one fixed 10 and one variable with $s[i]$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a glossary for symbols on these diagrams, however in this case:

- $f$ is some sbox, that is, some lookup table (and whose details must be given somewhere else in the document where this image is found)
- $\boxplus$ is either modular addition (modulo $2^w$, where $w$ is the number of bits in each line) or bit-wise exclusive-or.  Most typically, it is modular addition; however that usage is commonly used in conjunction with $\oplus$; hence the alterative meaning is possible.
- $<<$ is left-wise rotate, where each bit is moved a number of locations to the left and if a bit goes past the top of the word, it wraps around to the bottom; the  number of locations each bit moves is either $s[i]$ or the fixed value 10 (as shown in the diagram).  Now, $<<$ more commonly refers to a left-wise shift, where bits going past the top of the word are discarded, and we insert zeros on the right; however that would not make sense in this context.

The document this diagram came from should give more details...

Comment: Common, [RIPEMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD)

Comment: I'd say $f$ is some function, using an sbox to make it fast is an implementation detail.